# Screen Recording output get distorted on some Samsung Devices

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to capture a video of Android devices' screens, but on some Samsung devices, I got the video masked with a pink distortion overlay.

Check the below screenshot of output videos on Samsung DOUS and Pixel XL:

[image: On Samsung DUOS SM-G532F] -[image: Pixel XL 2 (OS Level 27)]

Samsung DUOS G532F(API 23) -  Pixel XL 2 (API 27)

Here is how I setup the Media recorder

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setVideoSource(SURFACE);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(recordingInfo.frameRate);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(H264);
    recorder.setVideoSize(recordingInfo.width, recordingInfo.height);
    recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3 * 1000 * 1000);
```

The default values used in `recordingInfo`

```
private static final int DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH = 540;
private static final int DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT = 960;
private static final int DEFAULT_VIDEO_FRAMERATE = 30;

camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth = DEFAULT_VIDEO_WIDTH;
camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight = DEFAULT_VIDEO_HEIGHT;
camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate = DEFAULT_VIDEO_FRAMERATE;
```

And the `CamcorderProfile`

```
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile;
    if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA)) {
        camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA);
    } else {
        camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    }
```

I tried also `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH` and some other profiles and it was the same result

Comment: Does this happen using your application only? -  Did you tried another screen recorder on that device? - Because there is a big potential to be a hardware issue.

Comment: Yes I did, other recording applications are working well on this device

Comment: Did you try changing your bitrate a bit? Maybe something like `setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000)`

Comment: I did also suggest you to take a look at: https://medium.com/jamesob-com/recording-your-android-screen-7e0e75aae260

Comment: @AmrBarakat I had the same problem, it also happens on a samsung device with me (the same problem you decribed pink color masking the video and sometimes green color).....can you please share the solution if you ever fixed this.

Comment: @data didn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile#hasProfile(int,%20int))  the `CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA)` may return `true` for unsupported resolution.

To ensure a given resolution is supported in LEGACY mode, the configuration given in [`CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP) must contain the the resolution in the supported output sizes.

`CamCorderProfile(int cameraId, int quality);`

e.g:

```
CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY,
            CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA)
```

And In order to get the camera ID list so you can get supported  camera ID list, you can do as follow:

```
CameraManager cManager = (CameraManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

---

Also the recommended way to check this is with [`StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(Class)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputSizes(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) with the class of the desired recording endpoint, and check that the desired resolution is contained in the list returned.

Sample of supported endpoint classes [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#PRIVATE).